# SSH locked out need to put files onto server

Tags: ssh, files, openssh, transfer

Okay this is my last hope

I have a server which i am locked out on because we were testing some different host files in the /etc/ssh folder. I am trying to get my back up onto the server so that i can then regain ssh. How do you guys think i should do it. I really lost and about to give up hope.

Comment: I think you've asked the same question several times now. @Oli has the same suggestion I made on your other question, which suggested you had physical access: Boot from different bootable media and mount/fix the system volume.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options:

- **Physical access.** Go up to it and log in. Or reboot into rescue mode and fix your hosts, set yourself a password, etc. Or boot into a live environment, fix the files or `chroot` and and set yourself a password. Many options here.
- **Virtual physical access.** If the server isn't *physically* yours —ie you rent it— your hosts might be able to give you virtual physical access. You'll have to prove you own it but many hosts can give you out-of-band access to a TTY or straight up root access.
- **Help from your host.** Many hosts are understanding. As long as you can prove its your machine (they can email/phone the billing contact) I don't see what incentive they have to not help. A good technician will be able to see an email begging "please can you fix my SSH configuration?!" and be able to help directly.

Short of that you're asking how to circumvent Ubuntu's built in security. Anything that let you do that would be a pretty serious bug, don't you think?